# Structure to model multiple hierarchies on the same entities

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, trees

Say I have a set of entities and multiple hierarchies based on them, each hierarchy modeling a different type of relationship. What would be a useful structure to model this scenario?

For instance, imagine this scenario:

- Entities are software modules
- There are two hierarchies in our mental model of the situation (I'm ignoring how we'd actually represent this on the filesystem for this question):

  1. "Technologically related" with edges from `JSON` to `AccountJSON` and `BlogpostJSON`, etc
  2. "Feature related" with edges from `Account` to `AccountJSON` and `AccountUI`, etc

One possibility is a labeled directed multigraph where the edges are labeled either `tech` or `feature`, but this misses at least one constraint: that if we look only at edges of one type they form a tree[1].

Another possibility is a [multitree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree), but that disallows diamonds, and we can have diamonds when using edges of both labels.

Suggestions from outside of graph theory are also welcome. The fact that we're starting with trees/forests makes me think of graph theory, but maybe there's a better way to describe what happens when they're combined.

[1] Or a forest if the entities in a particular hierarchy aren't necessarily connected.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ than for mathematics. I do not understand what entities or hierarchies are in your scenario; presumably entities are vertices, so are hierarchies edges between entities or something else?

Comment: @RandyMarsh: I could be wrong, but I think it only looks like a CS question because I phrased it badly. Another way to ask it is this: say one has two separate trees that share some, but not all, vertices. Is there a mathematical structure that describes this situation well?

I actually didn't think of this first in a CS context, but rather in a management theory context, since this is what happens in an organization that has multiple hierarchies.

Comment: Eg there might be a hierarchy based on role (junior accountants are overseen by seniors, who are overseen by CFO) and another based on location (a plant manager oversees accountants, engineers, etc for that plant, who is in turn overseen by a regional manager, and so on up).

One can model these two trees as a digraph, but that would be missing some constraints. I was wondering if anyone has named and studied this structure.